# i can't download excel sheet from ie11

Tags: asp.net

When I attempt to present the user with an "Open/Save" dislaog box to open or save an Excel file, I get errors in the following order, after IE displays "Do you want to open or save blahblah.xls?"

When I click Open or Save I get "blahblah.xls couldn;t be downloaded" with a retry and cancel buttons. I click on retry, it opens Excel and displays "The file you are trying to open, 'blahblah.xls', is in different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and .... Do you want to open the file now?"

If I select "Yes", I get a some error about missing files , all of them .css files, and then it tries to display the aspx page I was on in Excel (in an all mangled up version due to missing CSS files).

I have searched everywhere and can't find a solution:

Unchecked "Do not serve encrypted pages to disk" in IE Internet Options/Advanced

```
enter code here
 Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.   SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xls;");
       // response.Charset = "UTF-8";

        Response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.End();`enter code here`
```

Comment: Do you own the web server that serves Excel files, or are you just an Excel user?

Comment: i use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; to generate an excel,excel sheet are displaying correctly in chrome and it also work in some system ,i implemented  .HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); and  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";